<Select> elements not displaying properly after form submission
In my Next.js app, I have a form that calls a server action on submit. When the server action finishes saving the data, it uses revalidatePath() and redirect() to direct the user back to that page.
const returnTo = `/post/${post.id}`;
revalidatePath(returnTo);
redirect(returnTo);

This works as expected except that, when the page reloads, all of the select elements in my form return to an "unset" or default state.
Here is the simplified code for my form:
export default function EditPostForm({
    post
}: {
    post: Post;
}) {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { post: structuredClone(post) });

    const savePost = myServerActionThatSavesPosts.bind(null, state.post);

    return (
        <>
            <form action={savePost}>
                <select name="status" onChange={handleChange} value={state.post.status ?? ""}>
                    <option value="">Select&hellip;</option>
                    <option value="Active">Active</option>
                    <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                </select>
                <SubmitButton label="Save Changes" pendingLabel="Saving Changes..."/>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}

As I said, this works perfectly the first time the page loads. And, it works perfectly if you refresh the page.
However, if you click the submit button, the server action is called, and the data is saved, but when the page is reloaded, the select element resets to it's default value ("Select..."), not the value chosen by the user.
I've even tried putting a console.log(state.post.status) before the return, and the console shows the correct, actual value of state.post.status (not undefined), so it seems like Next/React knows the right value. It just doesn't cause the select element to display the correct value.
I haven't bothered to show the onChange handler, dispatch, or reducer, but I've confirmed that they are all working properly, since everything works exactly the way it should the first time the page loads, or after you click the refresh button.
It only stops working after you submit the form.
Another thing I noticed...

The first time I load the page, the select element correctly displays the value of state.post.status

After I click submit, the server action is called, the data is saved, but when the page reloads, the select element incorrectly displays the default value of "Select..." instead of the current value of state.post.status. I can confirm in the React developer tools that the value of state.post.status = "Active", even though the Select element does not show that value.

However, if I change any other element on the page, suddenly the select element also updates to show the correct value.


Thanks in advance for any help or insight!

When the page reloads, the component mounts again and useReducer initializes the state with the structuredClone(post) object, which may cause the form elements to reset to their initial values. Did you consider this possibility?

@AntonijaŠimić That's a good point. I did consider that, and it's the behavior I want. The select element's value is set to state.post.status, and that property has a value of either "Active" or "Inactive". I can confirm that state.post.status =  "Active" in the console and in the React Developer tools, even those the select element is displaying "Select..."
